# How to match an entity to a defined list of words in LUIS

Tags: botframework, azure-cognitive-services, azure-language-understanding

I'm using [LUIS](https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/language-understanding-intelligent-service-luis) to work with the [Cognitive Services Emotion API](https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/emotion-api) which ranks images for 8 emotions (anger, contempt, disgust, fear, happiness, neutral, sadness, surprise).

In my LUIS model, I have defined 'Emotion' as an entity and trained the model.

LUIS is correctly identifying the emotion entity but I'm stuck on how I map that to the 8 defined words that the emotion API works with (anger, contempt, disgust, fear, happiness, neutral, sadness, surprise).

For example If I send "who is the saddest person here" it will return this

```
"entities": [{
  "entity": "saddest",
  "type": "Emotion",
  "startIndex": 11,
  "endIndex": 17,
  "score": 0.967470348
}]
```

But how do I map 'saddest' to 'sadness' using LUIS or any other APIs?

Comment: can you show me one example of the examples you train LUIS with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved this myself by creating a single entity called `emotion` which has a child entity for each of the 8 emotions using the names that the emotion API uses (anger, contempt etc).

[image: Emotion entity with 8 child entities]

I then trained LUIS to differentiate between each emotion (child entity) using utterances and now LUIS returns something like this in response to a query like "who is the happiest one" (note I used the term 'happiest' rather than 'happiness' which is what the child entity is)

```
  "entities": [
    {
      "entity": "happiest",
      "type": "emotion::happiness",
      "startIndex": 11,
      "endIndex": 18,
      "score": 0.9464528
    }
  ]
```

Using this response, I'm able to determine which of the child emotions was recognised using the actual name rather than the text in the utterance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what your scenario is, so my answer may be a bit off.

From your description, I understand you want to create a mapping between entity types and the Emotion API's emotion categories. What I would do is create 8 different entity types in LUIS, e.g Emotion_Anger, Emotion_Sadness etc. and then train the model so that it recognizes these entity types separately. For your example, assuming you trained the LUIS model correctly, the expected result would be

"entities": [{
  "entity": "saddest",
  "type": "**Emotion_Sadness**",
  "startIndex": 11,
  "endIndex": 17,
  "score": 0.967470348
}]

Then, you can easily map the Entity type Emotion_Sadness to the sadness category.